# KDE Neon Boots into Intramfs, No Error

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kde, initramfs

I just installed kde neon, and after rebooting for the first time (not including the reboot after installation), the computer now boots into the initramfs prompt. This happens after the grub and the KDE Neon boot screen appear. There is not error, it goes straight to the initramfs prompt. Here's what I did before this happened.

- Installed KDE Neon root and swap partition on Hardware Raid 0 drive. Windows 10 is also on this partition. The home directory is on a non Raid solid state drive.
- Installed some miscellaneous software
- Installed nvidia driver 361 (This does update the initramfs so maybe there's some bad interaction with KDE neon?)
- Rebooted into windows
- Reboot into KDE Neon through grub and was greeted with initramfs prompt

Any advice?

**EDIT:** So I tried a fresh install to try to isolate the problem. It actually seems like the problem is that autoremove, which I ran after update/upgrade, removes a necessary boot elements. I'm guessing the upgrade was supposed to update said package and did so incorrectly.

Comment: just got the same issue and I remember the last time I booted I did an autoremove... Maybe I should use Kubuntu now instead and let neon grow first ;)

Comment: Ah, I was beginning to wonder if I was the only one having this problem. So I tried just sudo apt-get installing all the packages that would have been removed to make kde neon keep them on my system (since they're then labeled as manually installed) and I haven't had any other big issues with kde neon since then. Actually, aside from that one killer bug it's been much more stable than Kubuntu.

Comment: I already wanted to replace my kubuntu on my laptop for neon. Now I replaced neon with Kubuntu on my desktop. But yes neon is very stable overall and has many features I'm missing right now ;). Maybe I'm adding the repo of neon to kubuntu and see what happens :D. But this was a very huge bug - maybe fixable with an live iso.

Comment: Another Issue that I discovered, is that may icons in programs (like Firefox for example) are missing